# Add User To User Table In Terminal Rails 4 Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.1

I am using Rails 4 and Devise 3 and Postgresql for my database. How can I enter a user through the terminal into my user table?

```
rails db
```

is how I enter into the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ rails console

rails > User.create email: 'john@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password'
```